# Include folder and files in a console app on build

Tags: visual-studio, console-application

I am currently creating a console application which is reading from a folder which contains xml files, like so:

```
/Templates/Create.xml 
/Template/Update.xml
```

But when I debug the application it is looking for the files in `/bin/Debug/Templates` because I use: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

So it is doing exactly what i want it to ..but is there any way to get Visual Studio to copy the folder and files automatically to the Debug/Release folder?

At the moment I have to keep the two folders updated.

I have done this before in a Windows application, but I can't seem to figure it out in a console

**SOLUTION:**

I added the following code in Pre-build:

```
XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)Templates" "$(TargetDir)Templates" /R /Y /I /T
```

..and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio you can have post [build actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx). In this you can write command to copy the xml to the Debug/Release folder depending upon your BuildMode.

Update:

In Project Properties you can find this.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Check this commands which are available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I am aware of the build actions, but I thought there was a build in way to do it. I can only find this `Properties > Publish > Application Files..`  but this only works when I publish

Comment: I'll just make a little Command Line script then, thanks for the quick reply